# sorting array elements with condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, optimization

I have array like this

```
a =

24   700
10   500
36   560
50   240
10   600
30   500
70   450
10   200
```

the expected result is

```
a =

10   500
36   560
24   700
10   200
50   240
30   500
10   600
70   450
```

which means after meeting element(x) in first column with 50 or larger it should be sort elements according to the second column and after that it should sort second column elements from x to element of before next higher element.

can anyone help me??

Comment: no sir this is regard for project purpose. it's for some kind of sorting object position according to the centroide of the objects.

Comment: it's not very hard using `sort` and loop in loop in loop :D but I know that we must avoid using loops in MATLAB, so it's interesting to do this with matrices...

Comment: Hmmm can you explain what you want a bit more? This is pretty confusing ..

Comment: I supposed you can find the elements in column 1 which are larger than 50 and then you can loop through these indices. This will reduce the code down to a single for loop, which should be fairly effective. Note that you are actually not sorting a whole array for every index, which should keep the algorithm fairly effective as well.

Comment: Follow @patrik instructions, just be careful if there is a value over 50 in the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work here. It may be a bit rough and I have not tried to optimize but it does the job. I also added a number first to take the that possibility into account. The code is based on that you identify the elements which are >= 50 and iterate through each block.

```
function A = fun1()

A = [50,900; 24,700; 10,500; 36,560; 50,240; 10,600; 30,500; 70,450; 10,200];

idx = find(A(:,1)>=50);
idx(idx>1) = idx(idx>1)-1; % Elements >=50 is included in next block
idx(end+1) = size(A,1); % Include final elements

[~,tmp] = sort(A(1:idx(1),2)); % First iteration outside
A(1:idx(1),:) = A(tmp,:);
for k = 2:length(idx)
    tmp=[];
    [~,tmp] = sort(A(idx(k-1)+1:idx(k),2));
    A(idx(k-1)+1:idx(k),:) = A(tmp+idx(k-1),:);
end
```

Output:

```
A = [50   900
10   500
36   560
24   700
50   240
30   500
10   600
10   200
70   450]
```

I suppose that the value `[10, 200]` was an error in the expected output. Otherwise you have to include wrap around in the algorithm. This was not stated though, so I cannot really tell.